# Drawing points behind lines in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I am attempting to create a map using OpenLayers 4.

I have some vector tiles which contain lines and points. The lines represent roads and the points represent roundabouts. What I'm trying to do is draw the roads with casings and draw the roundabouts also with casings but with the casings for the roundabouts appearing behind the roads. Does that make any sense? :)

Here's what I'm getting at the moment:

[image]

Notice on the roundabouts how the stroke around them intersects the roads? That is what I'm trying to avoid.

The roads are styled similarly to this:

```js
const road = [
  new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#505050',
      width: 2
    }),
    zIndex: 2
  }),
  new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#ffffff',
      width: 20
    }),
    zIndex: 3
  })
];
```

I've simplified it somewhat to remove the colouring of roads based on their type etc as to not complicate my example.

The roundabouts are styled similarly to this:

```js
const roundabout = [
  new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 20,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#ffffff'
      }),
    }),
    zIndex: 1
  }),
  new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 18,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#ffffff'
      }),
    }),
    zIndex: 4
  })
];
```

Again, simplified to not include the extra circle in the middle of the roundabout, which is just the same point drawn again but smaller.

What should happen is the roundabout casing should be drawn first, then the road casing, then the road filling, and finally the roundabout filling. This should give the effect of the road filling and roundabout filling appearing to be one continuous line, and the casings flowing around the roundabouts without intersecting the road lanes.

The problem I'm having is that the `zIndex` values I'm setting for the roundabouts seem to have no effect at all. No matter what I change them to, I cannot get any part of the point (casing or fill) to be drawn behind the line of the road. I can change the `zIndex` for the roads to get the casing drawn in front of the fill, for example, but no matter how big a number I choose I can't get the road drawn in front of the roundabout!

Any ideas how I can fix this and get the points drawing as I would like them to?

Thanks,

Dylan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, OpenLayers renders points (i.e. your roundabouts) as vectors, but pre-renders lines (i.e. your roads) to images. This can be controlled using `ol.layer.VectorTile`'s `renderMode` option, which defaults to `'hybrid'`.

To render points and lines in the same pass (in order for the zIndex to get respected), configure the `ol.layer.VectorTile` with `renderMode: 'image'` or `renderMode: 'vector'`.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I decided to do it a different way by going back into a GIS and creating polygon data for the roundabouts instead so I could still use hybrid mode for other points such as labels and POIs. Without using a GIS though, this would definitely be the best solution.